# Name of theorem / result related to Grobner Bases

Tags: algebraic-geometry, terminology, groebner-basis

What is the name of the following theorem / result ?

There exist $x_1, x_2 ... x_n$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $f_i(x_1, x_2 ... x_n) = 0$  for each $i$ between $1$ and $k$ (i.e the variety is not null) if and only if the Groebner base of the ideal generated by $f_1$, ... $f_k$ is not $\{1\}$.

Comment: I think you are talking about [Hilbert's Nullstellensatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz)